# Overlayfs over archivemount

Tags: linux, fuse, overlayfs

I am trying to apply an overlay using `overlayfs` over a filesystem mounted with `archivemount`:

```
mkdir -p {upper,work,mount}
tar zcf somefile upper/ work/ mount/
mkdir tmp
archivemount -o allow_root -o fsname=ext4 somefile tmp
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=tmp/upper,workdir=tmp/work overlayfs tmp/mount
```

However, mount fails with:

```
mount: /tmp/test8/tmp/mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlayfs, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Looking at dmesg, I see:

```
overlayfs: filesystem on 'tmp/upper' not supported as upperdir
```

Why would archivemount not supported? Is there a way around that problem?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for the overlayfs kernel module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) states:

> The upper filesystem will normally be writable and if it is it must support the creation of `trusted.*` extended attributes, and
>   must provide valid `d_type` in `readdir` responses, so NFS is not suitable.

So `archivemount` probably doesn't implement either one of these features, which makes it unsuitable for use as a upper layer in a *writable* overlayfs.

Note that the documentation continues with:

> A read-only overlay of two read-only filesystems may use any filesystem type.

So if a read-only overlayfs is enough for your needs, setting it up on top of `archivemount` should work even for the lower layer, just having to mount everything read-only for that case.

---

Note that there aren't limitations in the FUSE protocol itself that make any FUSE mounts unsuitable for use as a writable upper layer in overlayfs.

Specifically, FUSE exposes functions to query and set extended attributes and it also exposes the `d_type` field for implementations to fill.

But specific FUSE applications need to implement those features for them to be available.

Regarding extended attributes, a separate technical limitation for `archivemount` is that not all archive formats support storing extended attributes, so it's possible even if `archivemount` would implement support for extended attributes, that it would not be available on all supported archive formats.

(See documentation for [`--xattrs` option of GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Extended-File-Attributes.html) for some more details.)

Comment: I missed that bit of the tar documentation. I tried it and it didn't help. Note that `archivemount` man page also mention extended attributes, but only for MacFUSE. I don't know if it means that they enabled by default on linux or they are just not supported on linux.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker Looking at the code, it doesn't seem like `archivemount` supports extended attributes, since the functions that would implement them are [commented out](https://github.com/cybernoid/archivemount/blob/717a27440c2b3fcb3496fa09eaebd2cc255d6d63/archivemount.c#L2711). Looking at the code, there are no references to `d_type` either, so it seems it doesn't implement that either...